# What are the Computer Management Group Privileges actually granted?

Tags: permissions, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

Someone wants to do something to database or it's server and they always ask for "Admin" privileges. Often on questioning it turns out they need to add a column to a table, so you grant db_owner on the database.

But sometimes they really do need elevated privileges on the server.  You could grant them 'Local Admin'; Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Groups > Administrators.  But this give god like access, and if it is a shared server, can lead to major issues.

Using a "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard" OS as the example. There are about 25 options.  The descriptions are less then helpful.

> Power Users are included for backwards compatibility and possess limited administrative powers.

So what can they do? No idea...

I Googled around looking for a list of actual powers granted for all of the options and have not found anything.  There is a good list for [SQL Server-Level Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx), but I am not finding anything like it for the Windows Server OS.

[image: ScreenShot]

**Clarify** 
The description for "Power Users" is included as an example.  I am not looking for it's privileges in particular. I want a list I can look at and compare to what the client needs to do, so I can grant the [least privileges required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for details about default "built-in" groups for the Windows platform.

You can find details about that in the Windows Server documentation for [Default local groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx).